# READ_CONTACTS permission is not working unless i manually turn it off & on on android SDK 23+

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions, android-contacts, runtime-permissions

I am working on an application where I need a user contact picture to be shown if available.

**Below is the code for asking read_contacts permission:**

```
  public void requestPermissionOrShowRationale(Permission permission) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission.permission)) {
        PermissionRationaleDialogFragment dialogFragment =
                PermissionRationaleDialogFragment.newInstance(permission);

        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG_RATIONALE);
    } else {
        requestPermission(permission);
    }
}

public void requestPermission(Permission permission) {
    Timber.i("Requesting permission: " + permission.permission);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { permission.permission }, permission.requestCode);
}

   public enum Permission {
         READ_CONTACTS(
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS,
            R.string.permission_contacts_rationale_title,
            R.string.permission_contacts_rationale_message
    ),
    WRITE_CONTACTS(
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CONTACTS,
            R.string.permission_contacts_rationale_title,
            R.string.permission_contacts_rationale_message
    );
```

**& permission call from the activity as below:**

```
  private void checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    if (!hasPermission(Permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        requestPermissionOrShowRationale(Permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine when I am using targetsdk 23.
after changing targetsdk to 26 or up the permission doesn't work.
unless I manually turn it off & on from the app permission settings to get the contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super easy and best solution i have found for my question is TedPermission https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission

I have removed all the existing codes for the permission and used the below magic code :)

```
  setLayout(R.layout.welcome);
    TedPermission.with(this)
            .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
            .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)
            .setDeniedMessage("This permission is required to show Contact Pictures and Email Address Suggestions.\n\nPlease turn on this permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
            .check();

   PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionGranted() {


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        Toast.makeText(WelcomeMessage.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a "bug" in earlier Android version in which once you request a single permission within a group, you'd be automatically granted the entire group.

So if you app needed READ_CONTACTS + WRITE_CONTACTS it would have been sufficient to ask for the READ_CONTACTS permission in order to get both.
Starting with Android SDK 26 this had been fixed to better reflect the documentation, so you need to ask for all the permissions you're interested in in order to get them, so the piece of code:

```
new String[] { permission.permission }
```

should have:

```
new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS }
```

(how to implement this with your `enum` thing you have there is up to you)